# playframework problem with routes:NoRouteFoundException

Tags: exception, routes, playframework

Trying out the custom editor portion in play tutorial,I created the routes as below

```
GET     /admin/myPosts/{id}                     Admin.form
GET     /admin/new                              Admin.form
POST    /admin/new                              Admin.save

GET      /admin?                                Admin.index
*        /admin                                 module:crud
```

and created the methods in Admin class

```
..
public static void form() {
        logger.info("Admin.form()");
        render();
    }       
    public static void save(String title,String content,String tags) {
        User author = User.find("byEmail",Security.connected()).first();
        logger.info("author="+author.getEmail());
        //create a post
        Post newPost = new Post(author,title,content);
        logger.info("new post="+newPost.getTitle()+" created");
        //set tags
        String[] tagArray = tags.split("\\s+");
        logger.info("tag array="+tagArray.length);
        for(String tag : tagArray ) {
            logger.info("tag="+tag);
            if(tag.trim().length() > 0) {
                newPost.getTags().add(Tag.findOrCreateByName(tag));
            }               
        }
        validation.valid(newPost);
        if(validation.hasErrors()) {
            logger.error("error in post");
            render("@form", newPost);
        }
        newPost.save();
        logger.info("new post saved");
        logger.info("going to index");
        index();

    }       
    public static void form(Long id) {
        if(id!=null) {
            Post post = Post.findById(id);
            render(post);
        }
        render();
    }
...
```

the views/Admin/index.html is

```
#{extends 'admin.html'/}
Welcome ${user}!! <span>you have written ${posts.size()?:'no'} ${posts.pluralize('post','posts')} so far </span>

#{list items:posts,as:'post' }
    <p class="post ${post_parity}">
        ${post_index}.<a href="@{Admin.form(post.id)}">${ post.title}</a>
    </p>
#{/list}
<p id="newPost">
    <a href="@{form()}"><span>+</span>write new post</a>
</p>
```

When I click on login ,the line containing the link `"@{Admin.form(post.id)}"` causes

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /admin?

No route found (In /app/views/Admin/index.html around line 7)
No route able to invoke action Admin.form was found.

play.exceptions.NoRouteFoundException: No route found
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:80)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:237)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:184)
    at play.mvc.results.RenderTemplate.<init>(RenderTemplate.java:24)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:659)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:639)
    at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:694)
    at controllers.Admin.index(Admin.java:33)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:543)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:499)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:475)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:470)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:158)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

How do I solve this?Can someone help?Is there a problem in the order of paths in routes?The `crud and secure` modules are available as per the startup messages

update:
the stacktrace as shown by play is here

[image: application error page]

I tried to change the order of entries in the routes file..Put the `* /admin path before GET  / admin? as below` ..Now I am getting a strangely rendered page

```
GET     /admin/myPosts/{id}                     Admin.form
GET     /admin/new                              Admin.form
POST    /admin/new                              Admin.save

*        /admin                                 module:crud
GET      /admin?                                Admin.index
```

[image: weird page]
This is where bob@gmail  ends up when logged in!
For the url `http://localhost:9000/admin?`,the page should be showing MyPosts link as selected..but here the Comments link is shown as selected..

So, it must be the problem with the order of paths in routes file...specifically that of `*  /admin?`  ..can someone tell me where exactly it should be put?

There was a slight problem in the routes file(a missing /)
complete routes file is

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

#import crud routes

GET     /admin/myPosts/{id}                     Admin.form
GET     /admin/new                              Admin.form
POST    /admin/myPosts/{id}                     Admin.save
POST    /admin/new                              Admin.save

GET     /admin/?                                Admin.index
*       /admin                                  module:crud

# Home page
GET     /                                       Application.index

# details of a post
GET     /posts/{<[0-9]+>id}                             Application.showPost
GET     /captcha                                Application.captcha
GET     /posts/{tag}                            Application.taggedWith
POST    /posts/{<[0-9]+>id}/comments                    Application.postComment

# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all
# Import Secure routes
*       /                                       module:secure
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

The admin page is shown properly when I omit the `Admin.form(post.id)` link in index.html

```
#{list items:posts,as:'post' }
    <p class="post ${post_parity}">
        ${post_index}.<a href="#">${ post.title}</a>
    </p>
#{/list}
<p id="newPost">
    <a href="@{Admin.form()}"><span>+</span>write new post</a>
</p>
```

As soon as the link is added

```
#{list items:posts, as:'post'}
    <p class="post ${post_parity}">
        <a href="@{Admin.form(post.id)}">${post.title}</a>
    </p>
#{/list}
```

The `No route able to invoke action Admin.form was found` error message occurs

Comment: Your CRUD route should be near the end, because if it is at the beginning, then all your other routes will not function, as the routes file is read in order. If you put the CRUD route at the top, it would intercept the route before any other /admin route is found.

Comment: Have you got the catch-all route in your routes file?

Answer (score 2):

The confusion was caused because ,in the Admin class there were 2 form() methods ,one with no arg,another with id as arg.The no arg method was placed before the other..causing the router much confusion..

The problem was solved when method form() was **replaced** by method form(Long id)

Comment: You also have a problem with the routes. /admin/? and /admin potentially direct to the same path (/? means the / is optional). Change the name of one of them to avoid unexpected clashes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is that route that is causing the problem? I have just tried this scenario and cannot recreate the error (although not using the CRUD and Secure modules), however as these routes come later in the routes file, these should not be causing issue.

I think it may be the following line of code causing issues.

```
 <a href="@{form()}"><span>+</span>write new post</a>
```

Specifically, this bit `@{form()}`

I think it should probably read

```
@{Admin.form()}
```

Comment: I tried that..but the error stacktrace points to the other line .I have updated the question with a screenshot..I tried to change the order of paths in routes  which then gave me strange results..

Comment: Your update is showing the CRUD page, because this is being found first, before your `Admin.index` route. I am not convinced that your problem is related to routes.